# Ubuntu hang, and cannot be soft-reset after resuming from stand by mode

Tags: ubuntu, standby

I have downgrade my xorg drivers, so I can hibernate and stand by my ubuntu smoothly.

However, in some case, there's a problem.

My ubuntu get hang. When I tried to switch to console mode (Ctrl+Alt+F1), then I cannot login.

The system always reply with an error whenever I tried to press a key.

When I press Ctrl+Alt+Del to perform a softreset, here what's it said:

```
[80141.320122] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 193687181
init: control-alt-delete main process (5660) terminated with status 2.
```

This error is not even recorded in syslog.
I guess this should be a problem with my hard disk since it said something about a bad sector.

Exactly, what kind of error is this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a cable problem, the hdd obviously, and maybe the mainboard. I can only think about these. You can check your HDD status with 'smartmontools'. Type: sudo smartctl --help || And you'll see the possible options. Well.. SMART is not always right but better than nothing. Anyway, if the hdd still got some warranty, use it, take it back. :)

Comment: Nice tools, except that I cannot understand what is this:
=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 73 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Sun Jan 24 22:12:21 2010

Use smartctl -X to abort test.

So, how do I know the result?

Comment: First, I found a good howto: http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html | Second, I mostly just dump the table out and check the raw codes. Most of them are easily understandable, and one can find a good description on Speedfan's site.